# Making numpy einsum faster for multidimensional tensors

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have some code that uses the following `einsum`:

```
y = np.einsum('wxyijk,ijkd->wxyd', x, f)
```

where (for example) the shape of x is (64, 26, 26, 3, 3, 3) and the shape of f is (3, 3, 3, 1), both having dtype=float

```
%timeit np.einsum('wxyijk,ijkd->wxyd', x, f)
# 2.01 ms ± 55.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This is too slow for my application, which is time critical. Neither using the GPU (via CuPy) nor path speedups (via opt-einsum) seems to make this any faster. Is there any way to make it faster natively in NumPy, or is this just about as fast as it's going to get?

Comment: You could reshape the arrays to (64,26,26,27) and (27,1), and use `@`.  But in my testing that doesn't improve the speed.

Comment: not sure about this but 100 loops may not suffice to amortise the initial parsing of the string into a set of operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use in this case the optimize keyword, implement it yourself, or use tensordot. All but, the first version should actually do the same thing (reshaping-> dot -> reshaping).

**Your implementation**

```
x=np.random.rand(64, 26, 26, 3, 3, 3)
f=np.random.rand(3, 3, 3, 1)
%timeit y = np.einsum('wxyijk,ijkd->wxyd', x, f)
#886 µs ± 3.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**With optimize="optimal"**

```
%timeit y = np.einsum('wxyijk,ijkd->wxyd', x, f,optimize="optimal")
#275 µs ± 23.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Reshaping and BLAS-call**

This normally leads to a quite comparable performance to `optimize="optimal"`, maybe in this case a unnecessary array copy leads to the slowdown.

```
def contract(x,f):
    s1=x.shape
    x_=x.reshape(s1[0]*s1[1]*s1[2],s1[3]*s1[4]*s1[5])

    s2=f.shape
    f_=f.reshape(s2[0]*s2[1]*s2[2],s2[3])
    return np.dot(x_,f_).reshape(s1[0],s1[1],s1[2],s2[3])

%timeit contract(x,f)
#144 µs ± 3.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

**Tensordot**

```
%timeit np.tensordot(x,f,axes=3)
#176 µs ± 4.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: `tensordot` does reshape (and transpose if needed) reducing the calculation to the `np.dot` that you do in `contract`.

Comment: The effect of `optimize` in `einsum` has shifted over numpy versions, as devs have tried different strategies.  On my version (1.18) it doesn't help.

Comment: @hpaulj I also have 1.18.1 Does using tensordot make a difference on your system? Maybe it is the BLAS backend for this very special case (use of dot-> gemm for a matrix-vector multiplication). I have MKL

Comment: Strangely, on my system, the naive version takes 2 ms, contract and tensordot both take 4.92 ms, while 'optimal' takes a whopping _5.42 ms!_ Is there some setting I need to change?

Comment: @DiehardTheTryhard Which BLAS back end are you using? `numpy.show_config()` Which CPU? All of your timings are really quite slow....

Comment: @max9111 CPU - i7-7700 @ 2.80 GHz; BLAS backend appears to be 'mkl_rt'. I thought MKL was optimised for Intel processors?

Comment: @DiehardTheTryhard I did my timings on a Core i5-8500 (dual channel RAM). I also tried it on a low-end device (Tablet with core-m3 and single channel RAM). There every method was in between 0.88 and 0.95ms. Your timings are far too slow for that hardware. I guess it would be the best to make a clean Anaconda installation and test it there.